# Render multiple object with different characteristic by OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es

I am a beginner with OpenGL ES 2.0. I have learnt about it for a few weeks. Now I can render multiple objects. However, I have a problem. My question is: How can I render 2 object: one rotates and one does not. When I want rotate a object, I use function esRotate() with modelview_matrix.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to call glDrawArrays() or glDrawElements() twice.  The first call would be for the model you do want to rotate and the second call for the model you do not want to rotate.  Only apply the esRotate() to the model for the first call.

Note that you will also need to call glUniformMatrix4fv() twice to reload the Model-View matrix for each model, with and without the rotation applied.

Comment: thank for your answer. Can you help me about texture? I want to set a image as background. However, I dont really understand how it work. Can you share any complete example code with me about this problem ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are lots of examples of texture mapping on the web.  Find one for the platform you are using.  This one is generic:http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/lessons_06__10/17010/

Comment: When I use 2D texture, we define "gl_FragColor = texture2D(s_texture, v_texCoord)", I know that v_texCoord is 2D coordinate {(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)}. However, when I work with cubemap texture "gl_FragColor = textureCube(s_texture, v_normal)", I don't understand exactly what v_normal is. Can you explain it for me? Thanks !!!

Comment: textureCube() works differently than texture2D().  For textureCube(), the texture coordinate parameter is a vector from the center of the cube.  It selects one of the cube map textures based on which coordinate has the largest magnitude. The other two coordinates are divided by the absolute value of the coordinate with the largest magnitude and scaled and biased to get the coordinate used to access the chosen cube face.